# Why the foreign key column of the parent entity cannot be updated?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have 2 entities: `Company` and `Address`.

In the `Company` entity, I have 2 columns that are associated to the `Address` entity:

```
Company:
- BusinessAddressID
- MailingAddressID
```

`MailingAddressID` can be initially equal to `BusinessAddressID` but eventually can be updated to different one.

Everything works just fine -- i.e., creating/updating a new `Company` record with similar business and mailing address, creating/updating a `Company` record with not similar business and company address except that the associated `MailingAddressID` column is not updating whenever I add/remove an `Address` record.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for both tables and the error message received when "the associated MailingAddressID column is not updating whenever I add/remove an Address record"

Comment: @Akina in terms of error messages, `gorm` does not return anything.

Comment: *gorm does not return anything* Nothing prevents you to copy the error message from MySQL Error Log..